# Get any character except digits

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to search for a string that has 6 digits, but no more, other chars may follow. This is the regex I use `\d{6}[^\d]` For some reason it doesn't catch the digits which `\d{6}` do catch.

#### Update

Now I'm using the regex (\d{6}\D*)$ which do makes sence. But I can't get it to work anyways.

#### Update 2 - solution

I should of course grouped the \d{6} with parentheses. Doh! Otherwise it includes the none-digit and tries to make a date with that.

#### End of update

What I'm trying to achive (as a rather dirty hack) is to find a datestring in the header of a openoffice document in either of the following formats: `YYMMDD`, `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD`. If it finds one of these (and only one) it set the mtime and atime of that file to that date. Try to create a odt-file in /tmp with `100101` in the header and run this script (sample file to download: http://db.tt/9aBaIqqa). It should'nt according to my tests change the mtime/atime. But it will change them if you remove the \D in the script below.

This is all of my source:

```
import zipfile
import re
import glob
import time
import os

class OdfExtractor:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        """
        Open an ODF file.
        """
        self._odf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)

    def getcontent(self): 
        # Read file with header
        return self._odf.read('styles.xml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepattern = '/tmp/*.odt'

    # Possible date formats I've used
    patterns = [('\d{6}\D', '%y%m%d'), ('\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d', '%Y-%m-%d'), ('\d{8}', '%Y%m%d')]

    # go thru all those files
    for f in glob.glob(filepattern):
        # Extract data
        odf = OdfExtractor(f)

        # Create a list for all dates that will be found
        findings = []

        # Try finding date matches
        contents = odf.getcontent()
        for p in patterns:
            matches = re.findall(p[0], contents)
            for m in matches:
                try:
                    # Collect regexp matches that really are dates
                    findings.append(time.strptime(m, p[1]))
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        print f
        if len(findings) == 1: # Don't change if multiple dates was found in file
            print 'ändrar till:', findings[0]
            newtime = time.mktime(findings[0])
            os.utime(f, (newtime, newtime))
        print '-' * 8
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work."  Fails to compile or throws exception?  Misses things that should match?  Catches things that shouldn't?  Please post a case that shows the error.

Comment: @djechlin Sorry. I hav'nt been programming much for a few months. And I hav'nt asking questions on SO for that time either. I should have asked the question better. I try to make the question a little bit more complete...

Comment: @djechlin I hope it is clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty stupid. If I add an `\D` to the end of the search the search will of course return that none digit also which I did'nt want. I had to add parenthesis to the part I really wanted. I feel pretty stupid for not catching this with a simple print statement after loop. I really need to code more frequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\D` (capital D) to match any non-digit character.

regex:

```
\d{6}\D
```

raw string:  (are you sure you are escaping the string correctly?)

```
ex = r"\d{6}\D"
```

string:

```
ex = '\\d{6}\\D'
```

Comment: This does exactly what the OP already has so it won't solve the issue.

Comment: That was an better and more obvoius way to do this. But it did'nt work. However I found another error in the script which made it work as I excepted.

Comment: But even so the problem bothers me :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
r'(\d{6}\D*)$'
```

(six digits followed by 0 or more non-digits).

Edit: added a "must match to end of string" qualifier.

Edit2: Oh, for Pete's sake:

```
import re

test_strings = [
    ("12345", False),
    ("123456", True),
    ("1234567", False),
    ("123456abc", True),
    ("123456ab9", False)
]

outp = [
    "  good, matched",
    "FALSE POSITIVE",
    "FALSE NEGATIVE",
    "  good, no match"
]

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{6}\D*)$')
for s,expected in test_strings:
    res = pattern.match(s)
    print outp[2*(res is None) + (expected is False)]
```

returns

```
  good, no match
  good, matched
  good, no match
  good, matched
  good, no match
```

Comment: But would'nt that catch `20120529` as `201205`? I don't want that.

Comment: Thanks alot for all your help! My mistake was a lot more obvious. :-/ See my update.